# Cusotm Recycler View [Android & Kotlin]

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view

How can I display the downloaded data as consecutive steps with links to neighboring elements, similar to the attached picture?

[image: Example of a required list]

Maybe I can use Recycler View? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use this lib
[TimeLineView Android Lib](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View)

In image that is given is generally called Timeline View

Well from the above given lib you can customise the lib by importing module in your project as per your need...this will help you

I hope my answer will help you
Thankyou

Comment: look into it had much features you can customise it easily by importing module